# Gnuplot - how to set wedges

Tags: gnuplot

How can I please set wedges in gnuplot in linux? I would like to write for instance ř, š, č, í, á etc. I have Version 5.0
I tried the following commands. Thank you!

```
set locale "cs_CZ"
```

Locale not available.

```
show locale
```

gnuplot LC_CTYPE cs_CZ.UTF-8

gnuplot encoding default

gnuplot LC_TIME cs_CZ.UTF-8

gnuplot LC_NUMERIC C

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; please post code as text not images.

Comment: `set encoding utf8`

Comment: it still skips those letters with wedges

Comment: What do you mean "it skips those letters"?   Where are these letters - in filenames? In text strings in your gnuplot script?  In a data file?  Are you typing these letters on the keyboard and they do not appear on the command line?

Comment: These letter are in strings in my gnuplot script. I write for instance:

plot '001' title "Světelné křivky" pt 7 ps 0.5

and there is writen "Svteln kivky" in the key

Comment: Do you use a font that is capable of displaying these characters?

Comment: Which terminal and output setting do you use? I do get wedges using `set encoding utf8;
set terminal eps dash enhanced size 8.5cm,7cm font "Helvetica,12";
set output "postscript_graph.ps";
plot 0.5*x-2 title "Světelné křivky"`.